WinCE не реагирует на сенсорный экран
Имеется панельный ПК Phoenix Contact (Ord.No 2404845) Type: BL2 PPC1000. На него установлена Windows 10 Pro 22H2, Сборка: 19045.2006. Установлен VMWare 16.1.1, на котором крутится виртуальная машина с Windows Embedded CE6.0. Сенсорный экран в Windows 10 работает четко и без нареканий, но как только захожу на виртуальную машину, начинает жутко криво работать, никуда не нажать, ничего не сделать. Но если подключить мышь, то на мышь реагирует как надо. Как пофиксить этот баг?
